# One character in a row

Tags: regex

I want to present character in the string as many times but only once in a row

Correct string: sdf.sdf.s

Incorrect string: sdf..sdf.s

How to check this situation by Regex?

Comment: Something like this: `s/\.+/./`

Comment: Look up [**backreferences**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match a string that contains twice the same character following each other :

```
/(.)\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to determine if a string has an instance of consecutive characters of the same type you can use `(.)\1`, the `(.)` matches any character and creates a back-reference group. `\1` matches the back-reference group so we are in effect matching double chars of the same type.

If you want to clean up the string then you can use `(.)\1+` and replace with `\1`, this will truncate any string of 2 or more consecutive characters of the same type to a single character. The addition of the `+`  is so that we match all the consecutive characters, not just two.